# Draw a irregular polygon on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, polygon, quartz-graphics, cgpoint

i have this question:
i have a array of points and i would draw a irregular polygon by this points with Quartz or similar.
Can you suggest me the best way to make this?

MyTest drawRect is this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 255, 0, 255, 1);
    CGPoint points[6] = { CGPointMake(100, 200), CGPointMake(150, 250),
        CGPointMake(150, 250), CGPointMake(50, 250),
        CGPointMake(50, 250), CGPointMake(100, 200) };
    CGContextStrokeLineSegments(ctx, points, 6);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UIBezierPath / NSBezierPath:

```
UIBezierPath *poly = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[poly moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
[poly addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0)];
[poly addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0)];
[poly closePath];
[poly stroke]; // draw stroke
[poly release];
```

Comment: How can I change the line color?
Can you get me the way differences with my drawRect example?

Comment: [[UIcolor redColor] setStroke];